# Peut-on m'expliquer ce qui ne va pas avec ma réponse?

Tags: discussion

J'ai posté une [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/25115/11921) hier qui a fini par recevoir un downvote sans explications.

J'ai cru comprendre en lisant certains posts en meta que cette communauté bénéficierait à recevoir plus de membres mais je pense qu'agir de la sorte n'encourage pas la participation de nouveaux venus. Une explication sur ce qui ne va pas serait la bienvenue pour m'aider à améliorer mes réponses futures.

Certes, il y avait quelques fautes d'anglais et une faute de frappe (qui ont été corrigées depuis) mais dans les autres communautés, cela n'est pas une raison suffisante pour downvoter. Si cette communauté à l'habitude de punir sévèrement les fautes, il vaudrait mieux prévenir les nouveaux arrivants.

Answer (score 2):

Seule la personne qui a downvoté sait pourquoi elle l'a fait, et rien ne l'oblige à l'expliquer dans les règles d'utilisation des sites de StackExchange. Si elle ne souhaite pas s'expliquer, c'est dommage et non constructif mais c'est comme ça.

Je comprends tout à fait la frustration qui peut accompagner un vote négatif anonyme, mais s'il s'agit d'un cas isolé et non d'un vote multiple ciblant le même utilisateur par le même autre utilisateur, il n'y a rien de particulier à faire.

Au fil du temps, si l'activité d'un compte est suffisante, les votes positifs, qui comptent cinq fois plus que les négatifs dans la mesure de la réputation et donc des droits associés, finissent en général par largement compenser les votes négatifs.

Pour cette question en particulier, c'est peut-être l'anglais imparfait du début qui a motivé le « downvoteur » (ou la « downvoteuse »), la présentation qui s'écarte des conventions du site, le non respect des règles typographiques pour l'emploi de mots de langues différentes dans un texte, peut-être que *if you don't sleep in the same bed* n'a pas plu, peut-être que l'incohérence grammaticale qui est apparue avec la correction (singulier/pluriel) en est la cause. Impossible de le savoir vraiment sans feedback du « downvoteur ».